# How to parse a string in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'd like to parse the following string which is a time (HH:MM:SS): `00:00:00`

Does anyone know how I can get the Hour, Minute, or Seconds values?

Thank you!

Comment: what a ridiculous question. You do realise that jQuery isn't a language right?

Comment: @SpliFF While you are right, I think a beginner may not know the difference.

Comment: Especially based on how often they are told to use it on sites like this.

Comment: Yes, I was unaware of JavaScripts split method - I mention jQuery simply because that's the framework I use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var time = "00:00:00";
var parts = time.split(':');

alert("hours: " + parts[0] + ", minutes: " + parts[1] + ", seconds: ", + parts[2])
```

Comment: I question your use of document.write in this day and age, but +1 for correct methodology.

Comment: I couldn't think of a better quick example of usage.

Comment: alert? less likely to interfere with anything they already have on the page.

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably go with the split(':') solution myself, but here's an interesting alternative using the native Date parsing:

```
var time = '00:23:54';

var date = new Date('1/1/1900 ' + time);

// 0
date.getHours();

// 23
date.getMinutes();

// 54
date.getSeconds();
```